# JSON parsing - best practice for converting

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a string variable that holds the string `[1,2,3]`. It is an array of integers. I want to convert this string to an actual array of integers using JSON functions, etc. What is the best way to accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to do the conversion looks like this

```
NSString *input = @"[1,2,3]";

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *output = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

if ( output != nil )
    NSLog( @"%@", output );
else
    NSLog( @"%@", error );
```

Note that the objects in the array will be `NSNumber`, with the values that you specified.

If you want to convert the NSArray of NSNumbers into a standard C array of `int's`, then add the following

```
int array[output.count];
int index = 0;
for ( NSNumber *number in output )
    array[index++] = [number intValue];

for ( int i = 0; i < output.count; i++ )
    printf( "%d\n", array[i] );
```